# Executable path error while using chrome driver with selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to open chrome using selenium but getting this error . I have tried many ways but still this issue is not resolved.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sl.py", line 11, in <module>
    chrome.Initialize()
  File "/home/daffolap/api_test/api_test/utils.py", line 14, in Initialize
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"/home/daffolap/api_test/chromedriver2.exe")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver`enter code here`2.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

driver=None
class Webbrowser:
    @staticmethod
    def Initialize():
        global driver 
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"/home/daffolap/api_test/chromedriver2.exe")
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        return driver
```

Comment: What OS are you on? your path looks like a *nix path but you are using an .exe file?

Comment: Make sure you get the right build for your OS from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=77.0.3865.40/